# Python: PIL _imaging C module

Tags: python, module, imaging

I'm trying to use a file that uses PIL and when I try to run it I get the following error:

ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed

I know theres a bunch of threads online about this but most of them see pretty specific. I'm 100% sure there is no problem with the code I'm running. Python version 2.7.2 64bit windows 7. I've been trying to fix it for almost an hour or so and I'm losing my mind. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

try to install pillow. you can install it with the command: pip install pillow

you have install the python-imaging??

sudo apt-get install python-imaging.

install first the python-imaging and next install the pillow

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving suggests that the C library required by PIL is either not installed on your machine, or the directory in which it's installed is not on your path.

I would follow the instructions here: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/faq.htm

- Search your system for _imaging.pyd
- Check that the location of _imaging.pyd is on your path
- Attempt to import the library from the command line with no accompanying code

If all of that works, please post your code, there is another problem.

Comment: Hi Nick, I have exactly the same problem as fastingaciu. I'm running Windows 7 64 bit too. I can confirm that I do have the _imaging.pyd, and that Python's path does point to the directory containing it. When I tried importing _imaging directly from Python command line, it gives me an error saying "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application".

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, the following command helped me (thanks to [this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149048/libjpeg-so-62-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory)):

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows, and had a problem ""ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed"".

The problem solved by installing Pillow from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil. (it's given by a post however I can't locate it back..)